# Alignment UIImageView to left with Aspect Fit in xib

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I want to align my images in UIImageview to the left. I am using Aspect fit mode. How can i achieve the goal using autoresiging constraints.
What i have done is as[image]

I want to align this little logo to the left.
[image]

Is there any way to set it using constraints and struts. I want like this
[image]

Comment: what is orange color ?

Comment: orange color is space??

Comment: orange one is imageview.

Comment: yes. . it is the free space of imageview

Comment: image is static or dynamic?

Comment: image is dynamic. . .

Comment: I have done it programmatically but i want to do it using constraints and struts.

Comment: how you do using programatically

Comment: just like this.                                                                                                  self.logoImageView.image = image;
            CGFloat desiredHeight = .18 * self.logoImagesContainer.frame.size.height;
            CGFloat scaleFactor = image.size.height/desiredHeight;
            CGFloat desiredWidth = image.size.width / scaleFactor;
            self.logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);

Comment: i am amazed no any ui expert replied yet. . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it programmatically. But still to head to set these constraints using ui-builder. If anyone know please share your knowledge with us.

```html
CGFloat desiredHeight = .20 * self.logoImagesContainer.frame.size.height;
CGFloat scaleFactor = image.size.height/desiredHeight;
CGFloat desiredWidth = image.size.width / scaleFactor;
self.logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
```